# /etc/default/keyboard not taken into account at boot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard, vagrant

I'm trying to have a Mac keyboard behavior on my `ubuntu/trusty32` virtual machine, and had some problems with it so far.

Using `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` seemed to work at first, but there was no way to keep the changes after a reboot, and the command `sudo udevadm trigger --subsystem-match=input --action=change` worked neither.

The `/etc/default/keyboard` content was:

```
XKBMODEL="macbook79"
XKBLAYOUT="fr"
XKBVARIANT=""
XKBOPTIONS="lv3:ralt_switch"
```

After some reading and tests I discovered that `XKBVARIANT="mac"` has better effects. I have now to type the command `sudo udevadm trigger --subsystem-match=input --action=change` to obtain the behavior expected, **even after a reboot**.

So I am wondering if I misread the sentence

> After modifying `/etc/default/keyboard`, you can apply the changes to the Linux
>   console by running setupcon. If X is configured to use that file too, then the
>   changes will become visible to X only if `udevadm trigger --subsystem-match=input --action=change` is called, or the system is rebooted.

How to make the reboot take into account the new keyboard configuration?